# How do you define the size and layout of a React app?

Tags: css, reactjs

I've been playing around with the simple alt examples here -https://github.com/goatslacker/alt/tree/master/examples/todomvc
I can't figure out how to resize it though - I've tried amending all the likely looking candidates within the css files but nothing seems to do the trick. What am I missing?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the size and layout is done in [base.css](https://github.com/goatslacker/alt/blob/master/examples/todomvc/todomvc-common/base.css) file. So in this app React does not know much about layout and sizing (I like a lot this approach). It is up to the style sheet to decide how to present a given component. There are some other strategies to use [style](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html) tag for React where your component layout will be somehow more attached to your React environment (personally I don't like that).

On the other hand, the overall design on this todomvc application is not great. First of all, it not responsive. And I believe there is a lot of fixed positing, which makes it harder to customize.

To fix your issue and ajust the width of your application, open `base.css` and change the [body style width](https://github.com/goatslacker/alt/blob/master/examples/todomvc/todomvc-common/base.css#L27):

```
body {
    font: 14px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    background: #eaeaea url('bg.png');
    color: #4d4d4d;
    //this is the property you need to change to adjust the width
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -ms-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Generally speaking I would not use this css as a reference implementation, but only the alt code. I would create a new css implementation based on flexbox.